# Any execution of command in vim causes it gets suspended

Tags: shell, vim

This occurs when I set the vim's shell to be interactive:

```
set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

or

```
set shell=/bin/bash\ -i
```

I like these because they give syntax highlighting to the output (eg.: `!ls`)
But the cost is that I have to type `fg #` every time.

Is this a default behavior?

How can I get interactive shell in vim without having to make it run foreground?

Comment: `shellcmdflag=-ic` is generally not a good [idea](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible/issues/29) as pointed out by tpope: "lying to bash about it being interactive when it's not. It affects everything from :! down to system() (:shell is always interactive), so it can result in all sorts of breakages if, for example, something in .bashrc produces output. I just tried on my setup and Vim suspended, for reasons I don't care to understand."  

I can also attested that many of vim functionality and plugins broke when this variable was set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This behavior is perfectly normal and expected and in line with Vim's author's philosophy. It's *very* unlikely to change in the future.

If you want a shell *inside* Vim, you'll have to install a plugin like [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) or [Vimshell.](https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell)

Comment: Could you please tell me what this philosophy is? (e.g. name, explanation, quote, or link)

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use tmux instead. You can split the terminal and have a normal interactive shell and an instance of vim running side by side - very handy.